# Minimizing mechanical energy subject to fixed angular momentum

Tags: energy, gravity, angular-momentum, friction

I may be in error, but this problem (ch. 4, no. 14 on p. 203), from Symon's *Mechanics*, 3rd edition, seems wrong to me:

> A mass $m$ of gas and debris surrounds a star of mass $M$. The radius of the star is negligible in comparison with the distances to the particles of gas and debris. The material surrounding the star has initially a total angular momentum $\vec L$, and a total kinetic and potential energy $E$. Assume that $m \ll M$, so that the gravitational fields due to the mass $m$ are negligible in comparison with that of the star. Due to internal friction, the surrounding material continually loses mechanical energy. Show that there is a maximum energy $\Delta E$ which can be lost in this way, and that when this energy has been lost, the material must all lie on a circular ring around the star (but not necessarily uniformly distributed). Find $\Delta E$ and the radius of the ring. (You will need to use the method of Lagrange multipliers.)

I gather that the aim is to find a minimum mechanical energy state, subject to conservation of $\vec L$, the angular momentum. It is easy to see that particles with non-circular or non-equatorial orbits can lose mechanical energy without losing angular momentum (simply convert radial or out-of-plane kinetic energy to heat).

That said, it seems that if there is any possibility of one particle transferring some of its mechanical energy to another (without which the problem seems silly), then one can conceive of scenarios in which unlimited mechanical energy is lost. For example:

Consider two particles, $A$ and $B$, each of mass $\frac m 2$. Let them each have prograde, equatorial, circular orbits, with radii $r_A$ and $r_B$ respectively. We then have:

\begin{equation}
E = -\frac {GMm} 4 \Big( \frac 1 {r_A} + \frac 1 {r_B} \Big),\\
L = \frac {m \sqrt {GM}} 2 \Big( \sqrt {r_A} + \sqrt {r_B} \Big)
\end{equation}

Fixing $L$, we can solve for $r_B$ in terms of $r_A$:

\begin{equation}
r_B = \Big( \frac {2L} {m \sqrt {GM}} - \sqrt {r_A} \Big)^2
\end{equation}

Now letting $r_A \to 0$, transferring just enough mechanical energy to $B$ to maintain angular momentum, and shedding the rest as heat, we have $r_B \to \frac {4 L^2} {m^2 GM}$. Thus the mechanical energy for $B$ approaches a finite value, while the mechanical energy for $A$ goes to $-\infty$, contradicting the problem statement.

Have I misunderstood something or otherwise erred?

Addendum: In case of worries that the above example does not conserve linear momentum, feel free to supplement $A$ and $B$ with mirror images on the other side of the star, so that total linear momentum is always zero.

Comment: You might have to resort to other conserved quantities, like the [Laplace-Runge-Lenz vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Runge%E2%80%93Lenz_vector).

Comment: I think the LRL vector isn't conserved under frictional forces? Without more details as to the mechanism of the "internal friction", it's hard to know what to conserve beyond the usual suspects.

Comment: Right, consider the relation between the magnitude of the LRL vector, $A$, the energy and the magnitude of the angular momentum. If $L$ is supposed to stay fixed, and $E$ changes, then $A$ must change as well. Although this would only mean that the magnitude changes.

Comment: Then again, $\vec{A} \cdot \vec{L} = 0$, which leaves us with only one other potential constant of motion. Long shot?

Comment: I haven't studied the LRL vector, but is it even defined for a multi-body problem? And if so, is there any reason to expect that $\vec A \cdot \vec L = 0$ in that case?

Comment: It's used for the two-boy Kepler problem and I expected this problem to fit in there. But it might not be the right way to tackle the problem, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts! Yeah, I think the two-body Kepler problem isn't really applicable here, since the frictional forces between the gas and debris are at play.